# Rendering HTML preview from Kendo Editor with Angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am attempting to implement the `Kendo UI Editor` with `Angular`, per the example on their demos website. So far it works pretty well;

## **[kendo ui demos](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/angular)**

This is what I have so far, but the problem I am having is actually rendering a fully parsed **preview** of the contents of the editor. When I use `ng-bind-html`, it works when the page first loads, but then any subsequent edits have HTML peppered into it. I thought the answer would be to use `kendo.htmlEncode`, but that isn't working either. I'm not quite getting the hang of this like I thought I would...

I have prepared a jsBin to show what is going wrong, as well as posted my code here for review.

## [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/tahitu/1/edit?html,js,output)

## app.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("kendoDemos", [ 'kendo.directives', 'ngSanitize' ]);
    app.controller('EditorController', function($scope, $sce){
        $scope.html = "<h1>Kendo Editor</h1>\n\n" +
            "<p>Note that 'change' is triggered when the editor loses focus.\n" +
            "<br /> That's when the Angular scope gets updated.</p>";
    });
    app.directive('kendoHtml', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                return element.html(kendo.htmlEncode(scope[attrs.kendoHtml]));
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

## html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kendo.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.sanitize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/kendo.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="kendoDemos">
        <div ng-controller="EditorController" class="container">
            <h2>Kendo Editor</h2>
            <textarea kendo-editor ng-model="html"></textarea>
            <h3>Kendo Editor Preview</h3>
            <blockquote kendo-html="html"></blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Prevent the editor from encoding its value.

   ```
   <textarea kendo-editor ng-model="html" k-encoded="false"></textarea>
   ```
2. Avoid using kendo.htmlEncode because it will encode it one more time.

   ```
   scope.$watch(attrs.kendoHtml, function() {
       element.html(scope[attrs.kendoHtml]);
   });
   ```

Here is the updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/bibecima/1/edit

You can also use ng-bind-html to avoid the need of a custom directive: http://jsbin.com/kamenoju/1/edit. It will work as expected once you set the `encoded` option to `false`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. The `ng-bind-html` was in the demo, but it lacked the part about using `encoded` to `false`. I think that the kendo documentation would do very well to update to reflect this, as it is very unclear.

Comment: Also, I am glad I do not need a custom directive. But this taught me some things about custom directives that will be very useful. Thank you again!